# Crosswalk plugin error: "requires the crosswalk project service to work please install it from the app store, then restart"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

So I have installed crosswalk plugin and everything went fine while developing. Then we gave our app build (apk in android) for some users to test before releasing it and we get the error message: `"requires the crosswalk project service to work please install it from the app store, then restart"`

[image]

We noticed this might be an error only for Android below 4.2, so is there any workaround/solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## New answer:

## Android Builds

A step by step tutorial of how to build ionic apps for android with and without crosswalk.

### Non crosswalk build

1. To generate a release build for Android, first go to ionic app root directory.
2. Then we can use the following cordova terminal command:

   ```
   #Generates the *-unsigned.apk file
   cordova build --release android
   ```
3. Go to directory `platforms/android/build/outputs/apk`, where we can find our generated unsigned APK file.
   **Very important: if the past command generates more than 1 apks, use the one that contains `arm` in its name for example: `android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk`.**
4. Generate private key using the keytool command that comes with the JDK. If this tool isn't found, refer to the installation guide (If this command doesn't work on windows make it on linux or a mac and pass *.keystore file through dropbox):

   ```
   #This generates key.keystore file
    keytool -genkey -v -keystore key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
   ```
5. To sign the unsigned APK, run the jarsigner tool which is also included in the JDK. **The jarsigner signs the unsigned.apk file** (If jarsigner isn't recognize as command just add it to environment vars PATH, usually the file is where the java bin are):

   ```
    #Remember to rename key.keystore and unsigned.apk by whatever this files are named in your system
    jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore key.keystore unsigned.apk alias_name
   ```
6. Finally, we need to run the zip align tool to optimize the APK (If zipalign is not recognize try adding it to environment vars PATH for windows; usually the zipalign tool can be found in `your/path/to/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign`)

   ```
   #If the zipalign isn't recognize try ./zipalign for gitbash or unix based systems 
   zipalign -v 4 unsigned.apk YouAppName.apk
   ```

### If you app has crosswalk

Pre-Build instructions

On Android, the app depends on the Crosswalk browser, and you must have in linked an installed before buiding, after generating the platform files

1. You'll need to add the corresponding ios platform and install plugins

   ```
   # ionic platform add android
   ```
2. Add the crosswalk plugin and required dependencies

   ```
   # ionic browser add crosswalk
   ```
3. Remember to test the app in the simulator on in GenyMotion before building

   ```
   # ionic run android
   ```

Build instructions

1. Go to the key store directory in the APP root
2. To generate a release build for Android, first go to ionic app root directory .
3. Then we can use the following cordova terminal command:

   ```
   #Generates the *-unsigned.apk file
   cordova build --release android
   ```
4. Go to directory `platforms/android/build/outputs/apk`, where we can find our generated unsigned APK file.
   **Very important: if the past command generates more than 1 apks, use the one that contains `arm` in its name for example: `android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk`, unless you are building for x86 devices.**
5. A valid key for signing the APP is already generated and available in toe android keystore directory in the project root.
6. To sign the unsigned APK, run the jarsigner tool which is also included in the JDK. **The jarsigner signs the unsigned.apk file** (If jarsigner isn't recognize as command just add it to environment vars PATH, usually the file is where the java bin are):

   ```
    #CD to the keystore directory
    cd android-keystore

    # Sign the generated apk
    #Remember to rename unsigned.apk by whatever this files are named in your system
    jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore key.keystore ../APP/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/unsigned.apk azanglogold
   ```
7. Finally, we need to run the zip align tool to optimize the APK (If zipalign is not recognize try adding it to environment vars PATH for windows; usually the zipalign tool can be found in `your/path/to/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign`)

   ```
   # If the zipalign isn't recognize try ./zipalign for gitbash or unix based systems
   # Remember to rename unsigned.apk by whatever this files are named in your system
   zipalign -v 4 ../APP/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/unsigned.apk AZSeguros.apk
   ```

---

---

## OLD answer:

I had this same error a long time ago. When your doing your build for the apk release for android follow this instructions this will fixed the problem (notice point 3, that is the particular one with the solution):

#### Building signed apk to publish in android with Ionic

1. To generate a release build for Android, first go to ionic app root directory.
2. Then we can use the following cordova terminal command:

   ```
   #Generates the *-unsigned.apk file
   cordova build --release android
   ```
3. Go to directory `platforms/android/build/outputs/apk`, where we can find our generated unsigned APK file.
   **Very important: if the past command generates more than 1 apks, use the one that contains `arm` in its name for example: `android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk`.**
4. Generate private key using the keytool command that comes with the JDK. If this tool isn't found, refer to the installation guide (If this command doesn't work on windows make it on linux or a mac and pass *.keystore file through dropbox):

   ```
   #This generates key.keystore file
    keytool -genkey -v -keystore key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
   ```
5. To sign the unsigned APK, run the jarsigner tool which is also included in the JDK. **The jarsigner signs the unsigned.apk file** (If jarsigner isn't recognize as command just add it to environment vars PATH, usually the file is where the java bin are):

   ```
    #Remember to rename key.keystore and unsigned.apk by whatever this files are named in your system
    jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore key.keystore unsigned.apk alias_name
   ```
6. Finally, we need to run the zip align tool to optimize the APK (If zipalign is not recognize try adding it to environment vars PATH for windows; usually the zipalign tool can be found in `your/path/to/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign`)

   ```
   #If the zipalign isn't recognize try ./zipalign for gitbash or unix based systems 
   zipalign -v 4 unsigned.apk YouAppName.apk
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing but I'm getting the same error, any clue?

Comment: @JoseIgnacioHita , hey jose try with my updated answer. Hope it might help

Answer (score 0):

On which devices you get the error message and do you use the sqlite plugin?

There is a known problem with the cordova and sqlite-plugin on x86 64bit devices (e.g. Samsung Galaxy S6). You can find the solution for this problem here: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/336